# Как правильно обработать WM_MEASUREITEM у TListView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

Как установить нужную мне высоту строк в TListView. Графика не нужна, форматирование текста тоже. Вот этот код я пытаюсь реализовать (нашел на форуме):

Унаследовался от TListView, обрабатываю:

```
TMyListView = class(TListView)
private
  procedure CNMeasureItem(var Message : TWMMeasureItem); message CN_MEASUREITEM;
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;

procedure TMyListView.CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem);
begin
  Message.MeasureItemStruct.itemHeight := 40;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TS2ListView.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or LVS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE;
end;
```

В родительской форме перехватываю WM_MEASUREITEM, шлю TMyListView:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
private
  procedure WMMEASUREITEM(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_MEASUREITEM;
end

procedure TMyForm.WMMEASUREITEM(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  SendMessage((FindComponent('MyListView') as TMyListView).Handle, CN_MEASUREITEM, 0,0);
end;
```

Я свое MyListView создаю программно поэтому ищу ее через поиск FindComponent.

Ну и не находит LVS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE. Если же я пытаюсь запустить без него - то ошибка при выполнении: Access Violation, указывает на эту строку:

```
Message.MeasureItemStruct.itemHeight := 40;
```

Comment: у вас код то компилируется? а то в одном месте `TMyListView` в другом почему-то `TS2ListView`. Чтобы не искать компонент, добавьте в форму приватную переменную, и там храните ссылку.

Comment: не компилируется, но только из-за этого - не находит LVS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE! Везде - TMyListView.

Answer (score 1):

Установить нужную высоту строк в `ListView` можно простым способом, все делается стандартными компонентами:

Кидаем на форму `ImageList`, задаем ему в свойство `Height` нужную вам высоту строк. В `Width` можно задать 1. Изображения в него добавлять не нужно. Далее в вашем `ListView` свойству `StateImages` присваиваем наш `ImageList`. Смотрим на результат и радуемся.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло! Но еще хотелось бы высоту заголовка сделать такой же. Это реально?

Comment: @AVM не знаю, с заголовком не пробовал. Обычно хватало установки более крупного размера шрифта.